# Jquery- ui Sortable with js list maker from array not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

So I am trying to implement a sortable list. But, the list is generated using JavaScript from an array. This array comes from back-end c#.

Here's my Sortable jquery -

```
       $('.sortable-list').sortable({
            connectWith: '.sortable-list',
            update: function (event, ui) {
                var changedList = this.id;
                var order = $(this).sortable('toArray');
                var positions = order.join(';');
                success: writeCategories(positions);
                console.log("positions written");
            },

        });
```

And here's my JavaScript function that generates a list ...

```
    function makecategories(array) {
            // Create the list element:
            var list = document.createElement('ul');
            list.id = "boo";
            list.className = "sortable-list ui-sortable";

            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                // Create the list item:
                var item = document.createElement('li');
                item.id = i + 1;
                item.className = "ui-sortable-handle";
                item.style = '"margin: 1px; width: 130px; padding: 2px; vertical - align: middle;"';


                // Set its contents:
                item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[i]));

                // Add it to the list:
                list.appendChild(item);
            }

            // Finally, return the constructed list:
            return list;
        }
```

Here's how I get my array from backend and call my JS fucntion

```
     var categories = <%= this.javaSerial.Serialize(this.Menus) %>;

        //alert(categories[3]);
        document.getElementById('categories').appendChild(makecategories(categories));
```

This is my HTML

```
    <div id="categories">
    </div>
```

This is the result I get -

```
    Hen
    Dog
    Cat
```

But this list is not sortable. Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Here's something I tried-

```
    <div id="categories">
        <ul class="sortable-list">
            <li id="1"> Food </li>
            <li id="2"> Drinks </li>
        </ul>
    <div>
```

This gives me a result of-

```
    Food
    Drinks
    
    Hen
    Dog
    Cat
```

Out of this the food and drinks list is sortable and the hen dog cat list is not sortable.

Please feel free to ask me any more info that maybe required.

Comment: In the sortable, you reference `success`, not sure what you are trying to use this for.

Comment: Oh so once, I get the sorted list, I call the function writeCategories() from backend and pass the sorted array- positions. The function writes the sorted array to a json file

Comment: can you point out what problem exactly you are facing because I tried your code in fiddle and it seems to work . [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/unvpqb93/)

Comment: @sandeepjoshi when I would pull array from c#, it was not sortable! But Twisty helped me solve the issue. So, Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider thew following example.

```js
$(function() {
  function makeSortList(arr, obj) {
    if (obj == undefined) {
      obj = "body";
    }
    obj = $(obj);
    var list = $("<ul>", {
      id: "boo",
      class: "sortable-list"
    });

    $.each(arr, function(i, v) {
      $("<li>", {
        id: i + 1
      }).html(v).css({
        margin: "1px",
        width: "130px",
        padding: "2px",
        verticalAlign: "middle"
      }).appendTo(list);
    });

    list.appendTo(obj).sortable({
      connectWith: '.sortable-list',
      update: function(e, ui) {
        var changedList = $(this).attr("id");
        var order = $(this).sortable('toArray');
        var positions = order.join(';');
        //success: writeCategories(positions);
        console.log("positions written", positions);
      }
    });

    return list;
  }

  makeSortList(["Cat 1", "Cat 2", "Cat 3"], "#categories");
});
```

```css
.sortable-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="categories"></div>
```

You can see this creates the List from Array items and then initializes Sortable once it has been appended.

Comment: OMG! This is genius, Thank you :)